# PHP script to count most viewed pages doesn't work as intended

Tags: php, mysql

A simple script I'm trying to implement into a website, to count most visited pages and present a top 10list as an output. Being an amateur still (in php/mysql) I can't figure out why the fields doesn't get populated with the appropriate data as the code is executed.

Here's the code:

```
$pagename = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
$sql = "UPDATED visits SET hits=hits+1 WHERE pagename='$pagename' LIMIT 1"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql); 
if(!$res) { 

}
```

Error handling doesn't show any errors, but the table remains empty. What am I missing? (I'm trying to do this by starting session as a root user of mysql so all privileges are present, and I've created the fields: pagename, hits.). 
I've tried to use other code:

```
*$sql = "CREATE TABLE 'yourDatabaseName'.'count' ('id' INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 'count' INT NOT NULL, 'page_id' INT NOT NULL) ENGINE = MyISAM;";
mysql_query($sql) or die('<p>Error, the count table was not created.</p>');
$query = "INSERT INTO count (page_id) VALUE ('$thePageID')";
mysql_query($query) or die('<p>Error, the Page ID was not entered into the table field.</p>');
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM count WHERE page_id='$thePageID'")
or die(mysql_error('Could not find the page id in the count table.'));
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
$count=$info['id'];
$count = $count + 1;
}
$querytwo = "UPDATE 'count' SET 'count' = '$count' WHERE 'page_id' ='$thePageID'";
mysql_query($querytwo) or die('Error, the count was not updated');*
```

And page_id/id fields would be updated, BUT not the "count" one (the error handling returns an error in this case tho'..). I'm sure I'm missing something simple here, as it's basically the same issue with these two scripts..

Comment: Spot on, everyone saw the wrong spelling UPDATED. Do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outside your wrong spelling of UPDATE, which of course is not the same as your second example,

I'm also concerned with what you have in the table column pagename. I'm guessing you have something like index.php. If that is the case and you happen to access a file from `sub/index.php`, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];` would produce `/sub/index.php` therefore returning false based on your `WHERE CLAUSE`. So try echoing

```
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
```

To see the result and ensure that your database have same value, directory and filename. Since I can't see what you have there, I'm also going to guess you have the file extension in there also and no extra characters.

If you fix the wrong spelling of UPDATE and the verify that what you have in your db matches what you get from echoing $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; Your first code should work better.

Comment: Yes thank you, I've just checked and it was true that I was filling that column with a wrong path (it doesn't seem to be the main issue still, with the hits column, but that was a step forward). I've just corrected it.

Comment: Are you marking the question as answered? At least now, I can go to bed. Do you still have problems or errors, let me see them. Which corrections did you effect. The spelling? Is your db hits column integer?

Comment: Yep, I can mark as answered (I've just registered here so I'm not quite used to the "drill" still). The corrections that made it work finally was correcting the path of the pagename according to a 'PHP SELF' output. Then adding a code that has been suggested by Wpearse (it will save me time by automatically adding a new page and prepopulating it with the '0' value in a hits column) and setting a pagename column as a primary key. Works like charm now.

Comment: Okay then, nice job to us all, see if you could upvote and pick an answer. Since the answer came from us both, make your pick. Glad to know your problem is solved. That's what Stackoverflow is for. We'd always build up reputations as we help more people. Still give your first code a try, it should work after the corrections stated. And don't forget to use `mysqli_real_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` for added security. Happy coding.

Comment: Yep, you both did help, so I'll just throw a coin :) (can't upvote still, I'l have to get some reputation first) And yes - I will use my first code, it suits better in this case.

Comment: :) Just before Throwing a coin. Have you got it to start working? Stick with what worked. And use mysqli

Comment: Yep, it does work as intended. I'll need to add a new column to be able to assign a full title for an article that's on a given page to be able to present a list of links with the titles (not just filenames as I can do now), but I'll try to figure that out on myself. It already has been a good learning experience, I'm just starting out. It's a pity I can chose just one answer, as I learned something valuable from all the answers that were given.

Comment: I just figured I don't know how exactly to implement the mysqli_real_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] in this case. Should I just replace the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; with a code above?

Comment: Since you are using mysql, use ***`mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);`*** But I strongly recommend you move to mysqli. Funny I'm still providing answers when my answer didn't get a vote up in the least. Use that as a replacement. You need the added security.

Comment: Ha, thanks once again. I've just re-chose the answer as you've put quite some effort to help me out on a nonrelated stuff (to an original question) too. Very nice new info for me.

Comment: Learning is an everyday thing, that's why we come to Stackoverflow. The learning is key, the reputation is fun to me. But I do give credits to @wpearse. I'm voting up his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update only updates an existing row. You'll need to add a row with the given pagename and a count of 0 first, before the update can increment the count.

Alternatively, try this SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO visits (pagename, hits) VALUES ('$pagename', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE hits=hits+1";"
```

Note also that your SQL query should read 'UPDATE' instead of 'UPDATED' :)

Comment: Very good suggestion (I've already learned more than I expected in 10mins since asking a question). It works as intended, EXCEPT the hits column remains "0" and it just adds the same counter.php pagename each time I refresh a page. Well at least I'm sure the database gets some kind of action from a script now.

Comment: Ah, right, change the pagename column so that it's a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

First thought... should this:

```
$sql = "UPDATED visits SET hits=hits+1 WHERE pagename='$pagename' LIMIT 1";
```

be

```
$sql = 'UPDATE visits SET hits=hits+1 WHERE pagename=' . mysql_real_escape_string($pagename) . ' LIMIT 1';
```

The reason its failing is because of the UPDATE(D) statement, I've modified your query as well so your $pagename cannot be 'injected', see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection .

You might also want to consider using mysqli, as mysql has been deprecated in the latest versions of PHP.

Comment: Thank you, I'll keep this in mind ("injection" safety) for a future.